# fixing OmniFaces BeanManager initialization issues when Tomcat starts

Tags: jsf, cdi, tomcat8, omnifaces

We have recently moved to Tomcat 8.5.4 (from 8.5.3) and to Omnifaces 2.4 (from 2.3), and we have also changed a few things in our Web Application. Since then, our Web Application does not start anymore, with the following exception in the logs:

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.omnifaces.ApplicationListener

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.omnifaces.ApplicationListener.checkCDIAvailable(ApplicationListener.java:77)
at org.omnifaces.ApplicationListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationListener.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4716)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDI BeanManager instance is not available in JNDI.
at org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager.<init>(BeanManager.java:100)
at org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager.<clinit>(BeanManager.java:49)
... 11 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.naming.NamingException: WELD-001300: Unable to locate BeanManager
at org.omnifaces.util.JNDI.lookup(JNDI.java:95)
at org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager.<init>(BeanManager.java:96)
... 12 more

Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: WELD-001300: Unable to locate BeanManager
at org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(ManagerObjectFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:94)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:840)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:160)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:828)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:160)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:828)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:174)
at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:163)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
at org.omnifaces.util.JNDI.lookup(JNDI.java:90)
... 13 more

Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4714)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager
at org.omnifaces.util.Beans.getManager(Beans.java:88)
at org.omnifaces.util.Beans.getReference(Beans.java:113)
at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplication.<init>(OmniApplication.java:70)
at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplicationFactory.createOmniApplication(OmniApplicationFactory.java:89)
at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplicationFactory.getApplication(OmniApplicationFactory.java:54)
at com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory.getApplication(InjectionApplicationFactory.java:93)
at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:142)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientWindowFactoryImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:405)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:251)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:543)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:283)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:328)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:236)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:439)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
```

**Our configuration:**

- Tomcat 8.5.4
- CDI Weld 2.3.5.Final
- JSF 2.2.13
- Omnifaces 2.4
- Primefaces 6.0
- An empty beans.xml file in WEB-INF
- A BeanManager resource entry in the context of our root Web Application
- Tomcat is started by our Java code (embedded usage).

**The BeanManager resource entry:**

```
<Resource name="BeanManager"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
          factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory"/>
```

We've moved back to Tomcat 8.5.3 and to omnifaces 2.3, and tried different combinations of component versions (8.5.3 with 2.4, 8.5.4 with 2.3, etc...) in order to identify the root cause of the problem, but to no avail.

Finally, we suspect a racing condition issue between the initialization of all these components (Tomcat, Weld, Onmnifaces, ...).

In a last resort, I have removed the BeanManager resource entry from the context XML file.

**Removed from the context:**

```
<Resource name="BeanManager"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
          factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory"/>
```

And it fixed the problem.

I had a look to the change logs of Tomcat 8.5.4, and I could find this change:

> Do not attempt to start web resources during a web application's initialisation phase since the web application is not fully configured at that point and the web resources may not be correctly configured. (markt)

I don't know if this Web Application's initialization phase issue reported in the Tomcat change logs could be linked to the problem we had. The reason why the removal of the BeanManager resource from the context fixed the problem is still unclear.

Any idea?

Comment: I can explain the (un)necessity of <Resource> in OmniFaces 2.4, but can you try OmniFaces 2.5-SNAPSHOT? Pretty much of CDI initialization was reworked/improved in that version: https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/281 and it works just fine for me.

Comment: With the omnifaces-2.5 snapshot version built on August the 31st, our Web Application correctly starts, no matter if the <Resource> entry is added or not to the Web Context. However, I'd love to know the reason why we had to remove the <Resource> entry with the 2.4 version :)

Comment: Okay, can you tell the root cause of the exception?

Comment: No unfortunately. I  have the feeling that it's a racing condition issue, as if omnifaces were trying to get an access to the bean manager before it is actually added to JNDI. The fact is that I don't have the problem with the latest snapshot of omnifaces 2.5, and I do not have the problem with omnifaces 2.4 if and only if I do NOT add the <Resource> entry in the context of the Web Application.

Comment: No root cause in the stack trace? That's strange. There should somewhere be an IllegalArgumentException indicating the exact reason of initialization fail.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood your question - I've added the root cause of the exception in the original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> javax.naming.NamingException: WELD-001300: Unable to locate BeanManager

This basically means that the `BeanManager` JNDI resource definition (as defined in `context.xml`) is found, but that the concrete `BeanManager` instance behind the JNDI resource isn't created yet.

This indeed matches the [described change](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_8.5.4/Catalina) in Tomcat 8.5.4.

> Do not attempt to start web resources during a web application's initialisation phase since the web application is not fully configured at that point and the web resources may not be correctly configured. (markt)

I can't tell the reasoning of [Mark Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1299005/mark-thomas) for this decision and there's also no issue link behind it. I guess he was trying to avoid confusing behavior caused by intermittently broken deployments caused by potential initialization ordering issues. This is perhaps a good thing, but I think Mark actually overlooked the possibility of defining the initialization order via `<ordering>` element in `web.xml` and `web-fragment.xml` files. I indeed recall that Tomcat never respected this as to invocation order of `@WebListener`-annotated or programmatically created instances (it however does that as to `<listener>` declared instances). Perhaps Mark should better have fixed that part instead of disabling JNDI altogether during initialization phase.

As to the change in OmniFaces 2.4, as per [issue 243](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/243) this version added a fallback to a Weld-specific servlet context attribute. This will be used when the JNDI resource doesn't exist, and Weld is being used as CDI implementation. Namely, Weld internally stores the BeanManager instance as a servlet context attribute too, so OmniFaces could just grab it without the need for JNDI. This means, the `context.xml` is no longer necessary. In Tomcat 8.5.4, you should actually remove the `context.xml` too because OmniFaces 2.4 still first tries to inspect the JNDI resource, which would eventually throw an exception because the `BeanManager` instance is unexpectedly unavailable as consequence of that Tomcat 8.5.4 change.

In OmniFaces 2.5, the CDI initialization has been reworked and improved  as per [issue 281](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/281) which describes the migration of CDI 1.0 to 1.1. OmniFaces no longer uses JNDI to inspect the `BeanManager`. OmniFaces will now use CDI 1.1-introduced `CDI` API.

```
BeanManager beanManager = CDI.current().getBeanManager();
```

This works regardless of JNDI configuration/initialization.

OmniFaces 2.5 is not final yet, but the 2.5-RC1 is available in Maven central as of yesterday.

Comment: All the more reasons to 'just' use JEE containers and not trying to include everything in a plain servlet container.

Comment: Thank you BalusC for your analysis. I'll use Omnifaces 2.4 (which is a great addition to JSF), and remove the resource from the context. I agree with you Kukeltje, but sometimes we have to maintain old code, or upgrade some parts of a plain JEE container  :)